# How to prove that $\operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname{var}(\mathbb E(X\mid Y)) + \mathbb E(\operatorname{var}(X\mid Y))$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Hey can someone tell me how to start, I have no idea, I need to prove the following:

$$
\operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname{var}(\mathbb E(X\mid Y)) + \mathbb E(\operatorname{var}(X\mid Y))
$$

Comment: Currently there is no question. You might want to add that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know the double expectation formula, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance#Proof . If you don't know the double expectation formula, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#Proof_in_the_discrete_case (and switch it to continuous using integrals if needed).

Comment: You can do the following: [double expectation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance#Proof). With [text](link).